# Sql query on xml data

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, xml

I have to get an information from a field where is there xml data only, like this ("Content" field):

[image]

i don't know how to use XQuery or other Xpath and i didn't find any beginner tutorial.
i find a Property Name (named "FormId" with a value which is the Id from an other table)in the xml which can be used for my web application i develop today.

How can i make a query so as to get this Id and use this on my ASP.Net application (SqlCommand).

I hope to be understood, because i'm a little frenchy who needs help on that technical issue :'(

The complete code here :

[Example of a complete xml data](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1P2-BHpMTUQEyoaAub2NBebpWVREztW7vGsh3o8sKXmI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: We're going to need a bit more to go on that just an image. Could you post some DDL and consumable sample data please? You can find plenty of guides out there on how to post SQL questions, such as [this one](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/).

Comment: That XML you've supplied is incomplete. If you try to `CAST`/`CONVERT` that to XML in SQl Server we get the error `Msg 9400, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
XML parsing: line 9, character 8254, unexpected end of input`. We need data we can work with. Hence **"consumable"** sample data and DDL.

Comment: @Larnu : My Question was updated. Sorry, i'm new on StackOverFlow.

Comment: The XML is still incomplete. We also need it in a format we can work with (so with DDL and an `INSERT` statement).

Comment: @Larnu : i make a google document and copy/paste the complete xml data in it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very bad design to place a fully blown XML as escaped text into an attribute's value... If this is under your control, you should change this!

Nevertheless this can be done:

First of all you have to read the Property "ObjectContent" and cast it to XML. In the next step you need to call `CROSS APPL ... .nodes()` as the needed value seems to be embedded multiple times.

```
DECLARE @x XML=N'Place on of your XMLs here':
WITH PropertyObjectContent(AsXml) AS
(
    SELECT CAST(@x.value(N'(/Root/StorageObject/Properties/Property[@Name="ObjectContent"]/@Value)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS XML)
)
SELECT AllFormIds.val.value(N'@Value',N'uniqueidentifier') AS FormId
FROM PropertyObjectContent
CROSS APPLY PropertyObjectContent.AsXml.nodes(N'//Property[@Name="FormId"]') AS AllFormIds(val);
```

If you need this for the whole table I hope you can modify this code to your acutal needs...

Comment: Thank you very much,@Shnugo, for this answer.Unfortunatly, it's not under my control and i can't modify the database. I have a question (but i think, it's not the right topic), do you think it is possible to work without SQL query, but with a ASP.Net code-behind ? i have to work on a web application so as to see each template with their own Form. Serialize the xml field ? Possible ?

Comment: @ClémentPraudel, Sure, it is possible to read an XML's content with .Net code. Read about `System.Xml.XmlDocument` and the methods `SelectSingleNode()` (to read the *ObjectContent*) and - after shifting this into a new XmlDocument - `SelectNodes()` to fetch all *FormId* values. One hint: Please do not place *follow-up* questions. On SO there's *one issue - one question*. If this question (*Sql query on xml*) is solved, please close it by accepting the most helpful answer and start a new question. Side effect: Much more attraction

Comment: Ok, so sorry about that. thank you for theses informations.

Comment: @ClémentPraudel No problem, you are new here... Happy Coding! (Is *this question* solved?)

Comment: I'm beginner in coding so "Google is my friend". I have an issue about how to connect the xml data to my app. I tested with sqlconnection but xmlDocument.Load works with an url... i posted a new question about that.